# Trying to check the words within one file in another

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm setting up a spell checker for a class assignment.

I'm trying to check the words within one file with another.

I'm currently experiencing an error:

```
spelling.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        if(checkMe.next().equals(dicArr[i])){
                                 ^
symbol:   variable dicArr
location: class spelling
1 error
```

Could you please advise me on what I'm doing wrong or what I could potentially improve with my approach? Many thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class spelling{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
  //read the dictionary file
  Scanner dicIN = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));
  Scanner spellCheckFile = new Scanner(new File("checkMe.txt"));
  String inputWord;
  int i = 0;

  //create arraylist to pass dictionary through, then I can define the size of my array
  ArrayList<String> dicList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(dicIN.hasNext()){
        dicList.add(dicIN.next());
  String[] dicArr = dicList.toArray(new String[dicList.size()]); 
    }   

 //Scan through checkMe file to see if the words occur in the dictionary
 Scanner checkMe = (spellCheckFile);
    while(checkMe.hasNext())
    {
        if(checkMe.next().equals(dicArr[i])){
            i++;
        } else{
            System.out.println("The word " + checkMe + "doesn't exist in the dictionary");
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(dicList);
  }
}
```

Comment: A local variable only exists in the block where it is declared. Therefore your `dicArr` variable only exists within the while loop block.

Comment: Thanks. I have now amended this. Any suggestions for my approach to solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your i++ is confusing - you should have 2 loops:

- one to iterate checkme, like you do: while(checkMe.hasNext())
- the other to iterate through all dicArr. Only if you check every dicArr[i], you can tell The word doesn't exist in the dictionary

Prefer this:

1 use a Set for your dictionnary

2 to check each word, you only need to do set_string.contains(new_word)

For example

Set set_string=new HashSet();

set_string.add(new_string);

if (set_string.contains(another_string)) ...

Set keeps unique elements. searching is straightforward.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Currently I'm only iterating through dicArr to check one word and never going to the second. So I need to have another loop which iterates through my checkMe. Thank you.

Comment: I've not used a Set (hashSet?) before, but I'll look into seeing whether it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `dicArr` in the body of a while loop. It is not visible outside the body of the while loop.

I am not certain what you are trying to do, but I think you need to close the while loop before the declaration of `dicArr`:

```
while(dicIN.hasNext()){
    dicList.add(dicIN.next());
}  // <-- Add closing brace here.
String[] dicArr = dicList.toArray(new String[dicList.size()]); 
// } // <-- Remove closing brace here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare this `String[] dicArr = null;` before all loop like this:

```
   String[] dicArr = null;
  ArrayList<String> dicList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(dicIN.hasNext()){
    dicList.add(dicIN.next());
     dicArr = dicList.toArray(new String[dicList.size()]); 
}   

  //Scan through checkMe file to see if the words occur in the dictionary
  Scanner checkMe = (spellCheckFile);
   while(checkMe.hasNext())
     {
    if(checkMe.next().equals(dicArr[i])){
    .....}
```